# After the end of footer table appear in same page in itextsharp

Tags: itext, footer

here is the endofpage event code

```
 public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {

            iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator line1 = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator(1f, 100f, BaseColor.CYAN, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1);
            document.Add(new Chunk(line1));

        }
```

Comment: Don't add to the `Document` in `OnEndPage`. It is only provided for reference. When that method is called, the area for use by the `Document` to add content is usually depleted, so where do you expect that content to go?

Comment: i  expect that content to  go after end of every page

Comment: solved by setting document margin at footer level

Comment: That might kind of work for your current use case. iText developers strongly advice against adding content to the `Document` in `OnEndPage`. Thus, chances are you will again and again run into trouble because of this.

Comment: ya thats true , actually i have removed document.add from OnEndPage too